# Salesforce.com Streaming API Error Summer 14 Release

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, salesforce

I have problem in Salesforce.com Streaming API using CookieJar.

"CookieJar::InvalidCookieError: Domain is inappropriate based on request URI hostname"

It seem that Salesforce is setting the cookie domain as ".salesforce.com" which will not match the corresponding request domain according to RFC 2109.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score -1):

Just add below to gemfile.

```
gem 'restforce', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.1'
gem 'faye', '0.8.9'
gem "cookiejar", :git => "https://github.com/MissionCapital/cookiejar.git"
```

Now create an initializer `rest_for` as below.

```
require 'faye'

Restforce.configure do |config|
  config.username      = ENV['SALESFORCE_USERNAME']
  config.password      = ENV['SALESFORCE_PASSWORD']
  config.client_id     = ENV['SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID']
  config.client_secret = ENV['SALESFORCE_CLIENT_SECRET']
  config.host          = ENV['SALESFORCE_HOST'] if ENV['SALESFORCE_HOST'].present?
  config.instance_url  = ENV['SALESFORCE_INSTANCE_URL'] if ENV['SALESFORCE_INSTANCE_URL'].present?
end

client = Restforce.new
credentials = client.authenticate! 

Thread.abort_on_exception = true
Thread.new {
  EM.run {
    # Subscribe to the PushTopic.
    client.subscribe 'YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME' do |message|
       p message.inspect
    end
  }
}
```

Just remember to use proper `host` for development and production. In development use `test.salesforce.com`.

Hope this help someone who facing the same issue.